# How to sync a github fork with different branches name?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a forked repository cloned on my machine and I have to update this local repository. The problem is that I have to sync my `code` branch with the `master` branch from `upstream` repository, it's not the default master to master update.

For now I'm trying to do this steps:

```
git remote add upstream https://url....
git fetch upstream
git remote pull upstream code:master
```

But it's not working... Can someone give an idea of what to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git's `rebase` command to rewrite your local branch's history to match that of the upstream branch. For example:

`git rebase code upstream/master`

Comment: Yes (I thought you want to sync your master with the upstream one)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First add a new remote like you have done alredy

`git remote add upstream https://url....`

Then checkout to your `code` branch using `git checkout code`

Then pull from upstream's `master` into your `code` by using `git pull upstream master`